# Is there a way to get the value from python code into YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

I'm creating a buildspec.yml file to build a docker image on ECR. The docker image has to be named as eg: "image-1.0.1". The value 1.0.1 will be received from python script. How to get the same value in a variable present in buildspec.yml?

Comment: You can use shell command language in various places in the buildspec.yml file e.g. `name: myname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`. Try something along the lines of: `name: image-$(cat version.txt)` where version.txt contains `1.0.1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use shell command language in various places in the buildspec.yml file e.g.

```
name: myname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
```

So, try something along the lines of:

```
name: image-$(cat version.txt)
```

where version.txt is a text file containing your version number, for example: 1.0.1.